# Scipy Optimize ValueError: Too many variables to unpack

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Trying to use the root method in scipy.optimize but keep getting a ValueError although to me it seems as I have entered the correct number of variables.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
earthpos=np.array([  1.50000000e+11,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00])

def equations(p,qf):
    q1, q2, q3, q4 = p
    r1=np.sqrt((qf[0]-mu2)**2+qf[1]**2+qf[2]**2)
    return q1**2-q2**2-q3**2+q4**2-qf[0]+mu2, 2*q1*q2-2*q3*q4-qf[1], 2*q1*q3+2*q2*q4-qf[2], q1**2+q2**2+q3**2+q4**2-r1

q1, q2, q3, q4 = optimize.root(equations, (1,1,1,1),earthpos)
```

Gives:

```
 ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)
```

Comment: let me know if my answer helps

Comment: It did, thanks a lot.

Comment: consider upvoting & accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

**Why you get the error**

You get the error because `optimize.root()` returns a `scipy` optimization results.
Type `type(optimize.root(equations, (1,1,1,1),earthpos))` and see the output.

**How to solve and unpack the solution of the optimization**

Replace the **last** line

```
q1, q2, q3, q4 = optimize.root(equations, (1,1,1,1),earthpos)
```

***with***

```
q1, q2, q3, q4 = optimize.root(equations, (1,1,1,1),earthpos).x
```

**By using `.x` at the end, you unpack the solution i.e. `x` from the `OptimizeResult` object.**

---

Putting all together, you just need this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
earthpos=np.array([  1.50000000e+11,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00])

def equations(p,qf):
    q1, q2, q3, q4 = p
    r1=np.sqrt((qf[0]-mu2)**2+qf[1]**2+qf[2]**2)
    return q1**2-q2**2-q3**2+q4**2-qf[0]+mu2, 2*q1*q2-2*q3*q4-qf[1], 2*q1*q3+2*q2*q4-qf[2], q1**2+q2**2+q3**2+q4**2-r1

q1, q2, q3, q4 = optimize.root(equations, (1,1,1,1),earthpos).x
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that optimize.root returns an OptimizeResult object:

```
Returns:
solOptimizeResult:
The solution represented as a OptimizeResult object. Important attributes are: x the solution array, success a Boolean flag indicating if the algorithm exited successfully and message which describes the cause of the termination. See OptimizeResult for a description of other attributes.
```

See here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.OptimizeResult.html#scipy.optimize.OptimizeResult

The object is made up of more than 4 fields, the field that you are looking for is the first one, so maybe `optimize.root(equations, (1,1,1,1),earthpos)[0]` will work? I'm sorry if this doesn't work, it's been a long time since I have programmed in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not runnable since you do not specify `mu2`.

Read the examples in the [documentation for `root`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html).  Also read the attributes of the [`OptimizeResult` object](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.OptimizeResult.html#scipy.optimize.OptimizeResult) that is returned by `root`  As pointed out by Abs, `optimize.root` returns an object, but you must use the `x` attribute of said object to access the solution.

You want to do something like (I used `mu2=1`):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
mu2 = 1
earthpos=np.array([  1.50000000e+11,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00])
def equations(p,qf):
    q1, q2, q3, q4 = p
    r1=np.sqrt((qf[0]-mu2)**2+qf[1]**2+qf[2]**2)
    return q1**2-q2**2-q3**2+q4**2-qf[0]+mu2, 2*q1*q2-2*q3*q4-qf[1], 2*q1*q3+2*q2*q4-qf[2], q1**2+q2**2+q3**2+q4**2-r1
sol = optimize.root(equations, (1,1,1,1),earthpos)
q1, q2, q3, q4 = sol.x
print(q1)
```